# Prove by contradiction that if $a\geq 2$ and $b$ are integers, then $b$ or $b+1$ is not divisible by $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove by contradiction that if $a\ge2$ and $b$ are integers, then $a ∤ b$ or $a ∤ (b+1)$.
I have that assuming to the contrary $a∣b$ and $a∣(b+1)$ then $b=ax$ and $b+1=ax$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Is that title correct? "a is not divisible by b".  Is that backwards?

Comment: Ok I'm confused. Let a=12, and b=3. 12/3=4 and 12/4=3. Ok if a=13, then a has no divisors. So it seems that some of the problem statement is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a \mid b$ and $a \mid (b+1)$, then there exist two *different* integers $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $b=ax_1$ and $(b+1)=ax_2$. Subtracting the two equations gives $1=a(x_2-x_1)$. Why is this a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a | b$ and $a | (b + 1)$.

Then there exist integers $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $b = k_1a$ and $b + 1 = k_2a$.

Substituting the first equation into the second yields the following:

$k_1a + 1 = k_2a$

$1 = a(k_2 - k_1)$

However, this is a contradiction because $a \geqslant 2$ and $(k_2 - k_1)$ is an integer, which implies that $1 \neq a(k_2 - k_1)$.

Thus, the logical negation of our assumption must be true:

$\lnot(a | b$ and $a | (b + 1)) \implies a ∤ (b+1)$ or $a ∤ (b+1) \quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\blacksquare$

FOLLOW-UP EDIT:

I just noticed that your title says that you're trying to prove that "$a$ is not divisible by $b$ or $b + 1$", however, in your question you write "$a∤b$ or $a∤(b+1)$".  The notation $a|b$ is read as "$a$ divides $b$" which is equivalent to saying "$b$ is divisible by $a$".  Likewise, $a∤b$ is read as "$a$ does not divide $b$" which is equivalent to saying "$b$ is not divisible by $a$".  This is backwards to what you stated in your title, however, the same logic with $a$ and $b$ reversed will yield an equivalent proof.